# How to save set data in case of any signal or exception using multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, set, python-3.8

As I'm using multithreading python I can't have threads opening the same file and write data so I save the data in a set then after all the threads finish I save my set in a text file.

I want to save my data in case of a termination signal or any exception before the threads finish.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

s = set ()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    handlers=[
                        logging.FileHandler("debug.log"),
                        logging.StreamHandler()
                    ]
                    )
valid_data = set()
def data_verify(e):
#data_verify(e) checks if e is valid with a post request to an Api for data verification then saves e in a set named valid_data
try:
     with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        run_threads = [executor.submit(data_verify, e) for e in s]
         #shows set with valid data.
     print(valid_data)
     #save data
     with open('ok_data.txt','w') as f:
          for d in valid_data:
              f.write(d+'\n')
except Exception as err:
     loggin.info(err)
     with open('error_save_data.txt','w') as f:
              for d in valid_data:
                  f.write(d+'\n')
```

I want to make in case of any signal or `KeyboardInterrupt` my set is saved in a text file before stopping the program.

Comment: So, when internally you find a corrupted data structure, you throw and exception and then save the corrupted state to a file? I don't find that a good idea, but it's your decision. Anyway, what exactly is your problem doing what you want? Please be precise which part doesn't work. Also, consider extracting a [mcve] if you want to demonstrate something, having your (badly formatted and thus unusable) code that includes (irrelevant?) logging is not helpful. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I have an api where I do post request to verify data, when I press ctrl c or a termination signal I don't want to lose the data in my set but instead save it in a txt file before finishing the program, then when I resume the program another time, I start where I left off. I don't want to lose the data I collected in the set.

Comment: I still don't understand what your actual question is. Please follow given links. For example, if your problem is to react to the user pressing Control-C, state that. If it's inter-thread communication, describe what you want to achieve and what the problem is. Make sure to tackle separate problems separately as well!

Comment: I'm putting data in a set, after all the threads finish I write data in a file, what I want is in case of keyboard interruption of a termination signal to not close the program until  the data present in the set is preserved in a file. how do I accomplish that? that is my question